# How to get ahold of BrowseDlg in wix toolset?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wix

I have a program with a working installer though i do wanna add one window for browsing files and picking one plus adding it to references for the app and I want one where you can browse to get a filelocation. I have seen that there is a BrowseDlg but I do not know how to access it in Wix? i do not have any idea where to start to get control over the predesigned BrowserDlg?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <?if $(var.Platform)=x64 ?>
  <?define ProductCode = "{A22947AF-0624-462F-91D7-042FBA975C74}" ?>
  <?else?>
  <?define ProductCode = "{4D5A783C-22C5-4D71-BA70-1AC08C70755D}" ?>
  <?endif?>

  <?define UpgradeCode = "{8F393562-E837-4F24-A53D-4E4D580915BC}" ?>
  <?define BuildVersion = 1.2.3.4?>

  <Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" 
      Name="!(loc.ProductName_$(var.Platform))" 
      Language="!(loc.Language)" 
      Version="$(var.BuildVersion)" 
      Manufacturer="!(loc.Company)" 
      UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

    <Package 
      InstallerVersion="200" 
      Compressed="yes" 
      InstallScope="perMachine" 
      Platform="$(var.Platform)"
      Manufacturer="!(loc.Company)"
      Description="!(loc.Description)"
      Keywords="!(loc.Keywords)"
      Comments="!(loc.Comments)"
      Languages="!(loc.Language)"
      />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeErrorMessage)" />
        <MediaTemplate 
      EmbedCab="yes" 
     />

    <Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="$(var.app.ProjectDir)\app.ico"/>

    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON">icon.ico</Property>
    <Property Id="ARPURLINFOABOUT">!(loc.helpLink)</Property>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLDIR" />

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo"/>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Assets\IconBanner.bmp"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Assets\Banner.bmp"/>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="$(var.ProjectDir)\Assets\License.rtf"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="appname" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="PublishedComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how the CustomizeDlg consumes the BrowseDlg in the WiX source at

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wixtoolset/UI.wixext/master/src/wixlib/CustomizeDlg.wxs

```
 <Dialog Id="CustomizeDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.CustomizeDlg_Title)" TrackDiskSpace="yes">
                <Control Id="Tree" Type="SelectionTree" X="25" Y="85" Width="175" Height="115" Property="_BrowseProperty" Sunken="yes" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.CustomizeDlgTree)" />
                <Control Id="Browse" Type="PushButton" X="294" Y="210" Width="66" Height="17" Text="!(loc.CustomizeDlgBrowse)">
                    <Publish Event="SelectionBrowse" Value="BrowseDlg">1</Publish>
                    <Condition Action="hide">Installed</Condition>
                    <Condition Action="disable">Installed</Condition>
                </Control>
```

Basically you need to use the [Selection Browse Control Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/selectionbrowse-controlevent) and share data using the _BrowseProperty.

I should note that this can only be used for selecting folders not files.  Custom UI work outside of MSI would need to be used to do this.  It's very advanced stuff so it might be easier and better to just defer this to application first run instead of the installer.